# Upload swf files using php?

Tags: php, file, upload, flash

This might sounds basic, but thought I'd ask anyway.

What I want to do is upload swf files into a specific folder so users can upload games, and I can have a look at them to make sure they're safe.

I'm not exactly sure how I'd do this though. Here is a simple code I found on w3schools.com that I tried modifying to no avail.

```
    <?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/swf"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "games/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "games/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }

?>
```

I changed the uploadable file type to application/swf, but when I actually upload a swf file, it just says "invalid file"

I've searched all over google for a swf file uploading script, haven't found anything, so I thought I'd try my luck here.

Thanks

Comment: Try "application/x-shockwave-flash" [http://www.gsp.com/support/virtual/web/conf/mimetypes.html]

Comment: Flash file uploading isn't any different from uploading any kind of file - perhaps except for the checking you will want to do to ensure it _is_ a flash file.

Comment: Using application/x-shockwave-flash worked, and also did changing the max file size.

thanks!